# Set the correct Accept HTTP header to get the parsed html content from GitHub repo

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, html-parsing, github-api

How can I set the correct Accept HTTP header for requesting another [Media Type](http://developer.github.com/v3/media/) (in this case as [Html](http://developer.github.com/v3/media/#html)) with GitHub's API? The current `content object` is always encoded as base64, but I need it as rendered html: `application/vnd.github.VERSION.html+json`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery-boilerplate/patterns/readme",
    headers: { 
        Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3.html+json"
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.data.content); // "IyNSZWN..."
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

I've also tried to use jQuerys `beforeSend`, no success:

```
beforeSend: function(jqXHR){
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.html+json");
}
```

**So the Question:**

Is it possible to get the rendered html without decoding the content:

```
decodeURIComponent(
    window.escape(
        window.atob(
            data.data.content.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "")
        )
    )
)
```

and parsing it later during a markdown parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `dataType: "jsonp"`. JSONP works by inserting `<script>` tags into the document in order to load data from another domain. And since a `<script>` tag works by just sending a GET request to the URL, without giving you the ability to set headers -- your `Accept` header is being ignored (you can verify that in the developer tools of the browser you are using). And since your header is being ignored, it is given the default value of `Accept: */*`, which loads encoded data.

The solution is not to use JSONP (`dataType: "jsonp"`), rather just use JSON (`dataType: "json"`). This will then force jQuery not to use `<script>` tags, but XHR. However, using XHR will throw an error since the data is on another domain and you will be violating the same origin policy. To get around that, set up an OAuth application with GitHub for the domain you are making requests from (your website that is making the requests), which will enable you to make cross-origin requests with the JSON dataType (this works by passing CORS headers). Read more about this here:

http://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing